# Symfony and Doctrine: mapping entities that live outside of a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a symfony project with some DDD flavor to it, and I'm trying to map my domain entities with doctrine and yml.

My (relevant) folder structure is like this:

```
src/
|_ Vendor/
    |_ Project/
       |_ Application/
       |_ Domain/
       |  |_ Model/
       |     |_ User/
       |        |_ User.php # entity
       |        |_ UserId.php # value object
       |        |_ Username.php # value object
       |_ Infrastructure/
          |_ AppBundle/
             |_ Resources/
                |_ config/
                   |_ doctrine/
                      |_ user.yml
```

My user.yml file is like this:

```
User\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    id:
        UserId:
            type: User\UserId
            column: id
    fields:
        username:
            type: User\Username
            column: username
```

And in my config.yml file I have this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    domain:
                        type: yml
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Vendor/Project/Infrastructure/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine"
                        is_bundle: false
                        prefix: Vendor\Project\Domain\Model
                        alias: Domain
```

No matter what I try, any doctrine operation such as Symfony's `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` returns `No Metadata Classes to process.`.

I don't know if I'm missing something here, it is the first time a try such an approach.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `User\User:` doesn't seem to be valid namespace in your doctrine mapping. Shouldn't that be `Vendor\Project\Domain\Model\User`? Did you clear your cache? ;-)

Comment: Figured to complete namespace after the 'prefixed' value. Anyways... Cache cleared. Tried the full namespace. Same output.

Comment: Another possible cause is that `user` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Try to change the table name and clear the cache again.

Comment: Further change the mapping's filename to `User.orm.yml` or `Vendor.Project.Domain.Model.User.orm.yml` and report back please.

Comment: Tried, same result. Further question: am I supposed to specify the prefix in the config.yml file and then the full namespace in the filename? I thought it would be enough with one of the two. Anyways... Always the "No Metadata Classes to process." single line response from the CLI :/

Comment: Try adding `doctrine.orm.auto_mapping: false` for a second. I have used a similar approach and directory structure x times with i.e. `User.orm.xml` mapping file name. The configuration under `doctrine` namespace looks pretty much the same. Must be a tiny cache-, naming- or indentation-issue I guess.

Comment: Did you double-check the PHP namespaces inside your entity classes, too?

Comment: Yeah, my classes' namespaces are correct, they're even unit tested with PHPUnit no problem. My problem is one of mapping and Doctrine, I guess...

Comment: Think I got it. The backslashes in `prefix`. Check my answer :)

Comment: Did you try `app/console doctrine:mapping:info`, too ? Does the mapping show up there?

Comment: You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after an exhausting process of trial and error, the working configuration was like this:

```
src/
|_ Vendor/
    |_ Project/
       |_ Application/
       |_ Domain/
       |  |_ Model/
       |     |_ User/
       |        |_ User.php # entity
       |        |_ UserId.php # value object
       |        |_ Username.php # value object
       |_ Infrastructure/
          |_ AppBundle/
             |_ Resources/
                |_ config/
                   |_ doctrine/
                      |_ User.User.orm.yml # namespace AFTER prefix from config.yml
```

User.User.orm.yml: # full namespaces

```
Vendor\Project\Domain\Model\User\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    id:
        id: # name is not anymore the name of the VO
            type: Vendor\Project\Domain\Model\User\UserId
            column: id
    fields:
        username:
            type: Vendor\Project\Domain\Model\User\Username
            column: username
```

config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: false
            mappings:
                domain:
                    type: yml
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Vendor/Project/Infrastructure/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine"
                    is_bundle: false
                    prefix: "Vendor\\Project\\Domain\\Model"
                    alias: Model
```

Basically, the mapping file name must follow the convention of .orm.yml extension, plus must implement the final part of the FQCN (the part not covered by the `prefix:` in the config.yml.

Also, in the mapping file, types must be FQCNs.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

**EDIT**: thanks [nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 issues with your configuration:

- the mapping-file is supposed to be named `User.orm.yml` (uppercase)
- the mapping-file itself should start with `Vendor\Project\Domain\Model` instead of `User\User`
- the table-name needs to be escaped with backticks or changed because `user` is a reserved keyword in SQL - `table: users`
- backslashes in the namespace in `prefix` need to be doubled (`\\`) or surrounded by single quote:
  `prefix: 'Vendor\Project\Domain\Model'`

Clear your cache after the changes.

From the [YAML Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings):

> Strings containing any of the following characters must be quoted.
>   Although you can use double quotes, for these characters it is more
>   convenient to use single quotes, which avoids having to escape any
>   backslash.
>
> :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `

Comment: For the first three bulletpoints: no matter what I do with the mapping in the bundle, I might as well delete it all (tried it). The result is the same. As for the prefix value, that's a good catch, but unfortunately, same result again :S